# How to secretly send a JWT token to a second application?

Tags: angularjs, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am currently sending a JWT token from one Angular app to another by using a query string.  Unfortunately, this makes the URL very ugly.  Is there a way to secretly / cleanly send a JWT token from one Express / Angular app to another?  If not, is there a way to clean up a URL after it has been set to an Express / Angular app on the querystring?

Comment: send it as a HTTP header?

Comment: Once the token has been seen in the query string, move it to a cookie and then redirect to a cleaner URL.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: That's part of the problem?  How?  Using Angular, redirecting the user to a new route simply appends the new path to the URL.  The query string is not removed.

Comment: Why can't you send it as an HTTP header as suggested by @MarvinSmit?